# Mysql innodb compression not giving proper results

Tags: mysql, compression, innodb

I was testing innodb compression(8kb page size). when i see in information_schema.tables it shows less size (around 10gb) but on disk it is consuming around 70gb..also when i use strings command over the file in disk,it shows data as it is as if it is not compressed.what could be the issue?

Comment: `SELECT @@innodb_file_format;` please.  What value is returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get 5.6.3 (or later).
`SET GLOBAL innodb_file_format=Barracuda;`
`SET GLOBAL innodb_file_per_table=ON;`
`ALTER TABLE tbl ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED;`

`SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'tbl'\G`